# Are Latin words "sidus" (star) and "sudus" (bright) related?

Tags: etymology

So, are those two words related? If so, how? Is one native and one a loan-word? Or are both loan-words? If so, from which language(s)?

Comment: *Sudus* doesn't really mean 'bright'. It's primary meaning is 'dry', and from there it also means 'clear' when applied to weather.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Sūd-* means "dry" rather than "bright", and might be cognate with English "sere" or might come from *sē-* "without" + *ūd-* "wet".

*Sīder-* is of uncertain etymology, but there's no real reason to connect it with the word for "dry". The two roots don't look especially similar phonetically.